# What it the difference between Pingback and Trackback?

Tags: blogs, trackback, pingback

What is the difference between the two names? Thanks.

Comment: I think that this question is more appropriate for Super User.

Comment: Not if you're designing a blog!

Comment: IMO, it's not a question about a general computer-related question, I'm asking here about developing a blogging platform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  pingback automatically finds URI’s in the post and pings them while a trackback needs to have a URI entered manually.

See this [Whitepaper: Pingback vs Trackback](http://ln.hixie.ch/?start=1033171507&count=1)

Answer (score 4):

Both Trackback and Pingback allow you to notify other URLs (webpages) that you linked to them from your page (e.g. a blog post).

The difference between both are:

- Trackback uses a simple HTTP POST request to notify the other side, while Pingback uses XML-RPC.
- Trackback support on the remote site has to be discovered by parsing the HTML source for some commented RDF, while the Pingback URL is sent as HTTP header.
- By using the HTTP header, pingbacks are possible for files other than HTML, e.g. images and videos.
- The Trackback specification leaves many things undefined, while the Pingback spec is very clear.
- The pingback specification requires pingback receivers to check if the original URL contains a link to them. This is not necessary for trackbacks.

What the others said about "automatic": This has nothing to do with both specs. It's your blogging software that (automatically or not) sends requests to the remote servers for any links in your blog post.

Answer (score 2):

Both Pingback & Trackback offer bloggers the facility to be in touch between websites.

Pingback:

- A writes a post on B’s blog.
- B writes a post on B’s blog mentioning/linking to A article.
- B’s blogging software will automatically send a pingback to A.
- A’s blogging software will receive the pingback. It will then automatically go to B’s blog to confirm that the pingback originates there (the link is present).
- Then A will have the ability to display B’s pingback as A’s comment. This will solely be a link to B’s site.
  Pingbacks also work within your site. So if one of your posts link to another post, then your WordPress will send a self-ping. This can get really annoying.

Trackback:

- A writes a post on B’s blog.
- B wants to comment on A’s post, but B want his/her own readers to see what he/she have to say and able to comment on it.
- B will then write a post on his/her blog and send a trackback to A’s blog post.
- A will receive B’s trackback, and choose to display it as a comment or not. The comment display will be a title, excerpt and a link to B’s blog post.

--Anurag Birthare

Answer (score 1):

Pingback and Trackback use different protocols. Pingback is automatic and Trackback is manual. You can read up on the difference on [Geeklog](http://www.geeklog.net/docs/english/trackback.html).

Answer (score -1):

Trackback URL receives a copy of the originating server's address. If enabled, a Pingback is sent to the originating server's URL to verify that it is not a spam Trackback.